# Google App Script Spreadsheet Add-on: Allow people outside of my organization to test it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a Google Apps Script that implements spreadsheet add-on functionality. I and everyone in my organization can test it (via Run > Test as add-on). Now I want to allow one specific person outside of my organization to be able to test it as well, without having to publish it.

As far as I understand it from the information I found so far, there are only three permission schemes for scripts: private for me, private for my organization, public for everyone. Is that correct or is there a way to grant access to specific persons?

That person has a Google account, just outside of my organization, and has access to both the App Script and the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission schemes you're mentioning (private for me, private for my organization, public for everyone) it's the Add-on visibility [1], which only applies for published Add-ons. You or any user with at least read permission on the Add-on's script and Spreadsheet can test the Add-on without having to publish it following these steps from the documentation [2]:

> 1) Open the add-on's script project in the Apps Script editor.
>
> 2) Select Publish > Deploy from manifest... to open the Deployments
>   dialog.
>
> 3) In the Latest Version (Head) row, click Install add-on to install
>   the currently saved version of the add-on in development-mode. If you
>   install the Latest Version (Head) of the add-on, any changes you make
>   to the add-on code are applied immediately without you needing to
>   reinstall it.
>
> 4) Alternatively, you can create a versioned deployment and install
>   that instead. This can be helpful if you want to 'checkpoint' a
>   version of the add-on to compare it to the version under development.

[1] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/editor-publish-overview#visibility

[2] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons

Comment: Thanks! For me it works if I try it with my non-organizational Google account. Just wondering how one picks a particular deployment to test and how it interacts with other deployments. Some day ago I tried "Deploy as add-on" and created an according project in GSuite, and then the other guy always got the error `org_internal: This client is restricted to users within its organization.` Now I deleted that project and he gets the error `deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.` So it seems he accesses the add-on deployment and not the manifest deployment? I'm a bit lost, sorry.

Comment: Yes exactly you have to use the "Deploy from manifest" option. If you use "Deploy as add-on" you'll only have the 3 visibility options you talked about: private for me, private for my organization, public for everyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It finally starts to make sense.